Authentication fails with username and password firebase authentication
Goal
Register and login with username and password via custom token functionality in Firebase (instead of using email and password). Please note that I am new to javascript and making APIs in python.
My attempt
Code is provided below. I run a flask server with python main.py that provides a custom token. Then app.js should receive the token and signInWithCustomToken. But the console in index.html shows POST http://localhost:5000/get_custom_token 401 (UNAUTHORIZED). What am I missing/doing incorrectly?
Example code
Python backend
import hashlib
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes

def initialize_firebase_admin():
  # Path to your service account key file
  cred = credentials.Certificate('myJSONfile.json')
  firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

initialize_firebase_admin()

# Mock database
user_db = {}

# Functions
def hash_password(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()

def register_user(username, password):
    if username in user_db:
        raise ValueError("Username already exists")
    hashed_password = hash_password(password)
    user_db[username] = hashed_password
    print(f"User {username} registered successfully")

def authenticate_user(username, password):
    hashed_password = hash_password(password)
    stored_password = user_db.get(username)
    if stored_password and stored_password == hashed_password:
        return True
    return False

def generate_custom_token(uid):
    custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid)
    return custom_token
  
  
# App
@app.route('/get_custom_token', methods=['POST'])
def get_custom_token():
    data = request.json
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')

    print(f"Received login attempt for user: {username}")

    if authenticate_user(username, password):
        uid = username  # Use username as uid
        token = generate_custom_token(uid)
        print(f"Generated custom token for user: {username}")
        return jsonify({'token': token})
    else:
        print("Authentication failed for user: ", username)
        return jsonify({'error': 'Authentication failed'}), 401

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    data = request.json
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')

    try:
        register_user(username, password)
        print(f"User {username} registered successfully")
        return jsonify({'message': 'User registered successfully'})
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

app.js
// Web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


async function getCustomToken(username, password) {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/get_custom_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.token;
    } else {
        const error = await response.json();
        throw new Error(error.error);
    }
}

async function signInWithCustomToken(customToken) {
    try {
        const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
        console.log("User signed in: ", userCredential.user);
        // You can now use the authenticated user information
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error signing in: ", error.code, error.message);
    }
}

async function authenticate(username, password) {
    try {
        const customToken = await getCustomToken(username, password);
        await signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed: ", error.message);
    }
}

// Example usage
const username = "user1";
const password = "password123";
authenticate(username, password);

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Firebase Authentication</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Firebase Custom Authentication</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

